# Dissecting a string

Tags: php, string, variables, slice

I suspect that this has been asked before, but I have no idea what it's actually called, so I couldn't find anything.

I am creating a browser based game in which the player has a 10x10 grid. Each grid square has a few aspects to it, some as binary flags and other as hex values.

To store this information in an array, I want a given cell to contain the following:

"9A0101" where 9A is the tile type, and the 0s and 1s are binary flags about that map tile.

I want to be able to take "9A0101" and split it into "9A", "0", "1", "0", and "1" as separate variables.

TLDR:

How do I slice up a string in PHP? The string will always be the same length, and the parts where I want to cut it will always be at the same offsets.

Comment: Is there a reason you're serializing the data like that?  The array can store nested arrays like this: `array('type' => 0x9A, 'flags' => 5)`.

Comment: yes - i will be storing and working with the grid from a 10 row, 10 column mysql table. from what i understand, that's the best way to work with such things in an sql table - though if i'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: you should rework your database design, serailized data is deadly in selects and you will stumble upon lots of things you cant do with that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about `substr()` ? :

```
<?php
$str = '9A0101';
echo substr($str,0,2); 
echo substr($str,2,1); 
echo substr($str,3,1);
echo substr($str,4,1); 
echo substr($str,5,1); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the parts of string

```
<?php
echo substr('9A0101', 0,2);     // 9A
echo substr('9A0101', 2, 1);  // 0
echo substr('9A0101', 3, 1);  // 1
echo substr('9A0101', 4, 1);  // 0
echo substr('9A0101', 5, 1);  // 1
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the substr() function

```
<?php
$str = "9A0101";
$arr = Array();

$arr[0] = substr($str, -6, 2);
$arr[1] = substr($str, -4, 1);
$arr[2] = substr($str, -3, 1);
$arr[3] = substr($str, -2, 1);
$arr[4] = substr($str, -1, 1);

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo($key . "=>" . $val . '<br/>');
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe can use the str_split() function.

```
$str = "9A0101";

//splitting the string
$array = str_split($str, 2);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single function call, regex can serve you well.

```
preg_split('~(^..|.)\K~', $string);
```

The above will split the string on the zero-width position *after* the first two characters of the string or each subsequent character.  `\K` means forget what is already matched.

If you want to save the 5 values as individual variables, then you can use `list()` or array destructuring syntax. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/faZEM)

```
[$type, $one, $two, $three, $four] = preg_split('~(^..|.)\K~', $string);
```

---

If you wish, you can even access the single byte characters by their string offset. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/JLD5L)

```
$type = $string[0] . $string[1];
$one = $string[2];
$two = $string[3];
$three = $string[4];
$four = $string[5];
```